# Terse way of writing "if key1 or key2 are not in dict" Python

Tags: python

Simple question, just wondering if there's a shorter way to check for a key being in a dict than writing it out twice like this:

`if "bar" not in foo.keys() or "baz" not in foo.keys():`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use list comprehension with `any` or `all` and a list of keys to do different checks for the keys in a dictionary. Depending what logic you actually want to check there are several ways of doing it with these methods.

**Any keys are missing from the dict**

*This is what your example code does.*

Equivalent to `if "bar" not in foo or "baz" not in foo:`

```py
if any(k not in foo for k in ["bar", "baz"]):
# or
if not all(k in foo for k in ["bar", "baz"]):
```

**None of the keys are in the dict**

Equivalent to `if "bar" not in foo and "baz" not in foo:`

```py
if not any(k in foo for k in ["bar", "baz"]):
```

**All the keys are in the dict**

Equivalent to `if "bar" in foo and "baz" in foo:`

```py
if all(k in foo for k in ["bar", "baz"]):
```

If there are a lot of keys to check, you can pull it out into a separate list and keep the if statement constant length

```py
key_list = ["bar","bax","baz","bor","bam"]
if all(k in foo for k in key_list):
```

Comment: I would emphasise the `all` variant, that's the equivalent of what the question asked for,

Comment: @paxdiablo if the question wanted all I would think they would have written `"bar" in foo and "baz" in foo` - but it wasn't clear if that was just an example syntax or what they actually wanted.

Comment: `if bar not in foo or baz not in foo` (from the question) will be false unless BOTH bar and baz are there. Hence your `if all(k in foo for k in [bar,baz])` is the correct one.

Comment: @paxdiablo Make a test program and try it if you  don't believe me - the condition will be true if any key is missing, so the same as `if any(k not in foo ...)` or `if not all(k in foo ...)`

Comment: Yes, your middle two return the correct result. The first and the last do not, meaning my specific advice was wrong but the idea was still right :-) All do what you *say,* but they do not do what the OP requested. Hence it would be good to mark the middle two somehow (move them to the top or indicate that they are the two that give the specific results for the OP).

Comment: @paxdiablo Fair enough - I edited the answer to make that more clear.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to call keys

```py
if "bar" not in foo or "baz" not in foo:
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if "bar" not in foo.keys() or "baz" not in foo.keys():
```

is the same as:

```
if "bar" not in foo or "baz" not in foo:
```

is the same as:

```
if not ("bar" in foo and "baz" in foo):
```

is the same as:

```
if not all(key in foo for key in ("bar", "baz")):
```

is the same as:

```
if not {"bar", "baz"}.issubset(foo):
```

The latter is what I'd use, especially if I had a bunch of values to test.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `foo` is a dictionary, you don't need to write `.keys()`.

`"bar" in foo` will work and is shorter.

Using `any()` is bit neater but not really shorter:

```
if any(x not in foo for x in ["bar", "baz"]):
```

If you were checking for more than two keys, `any()` would definitely be shorter.